# How to understand segmented binomial heaps described in <Purely Functional Data Structures>

Tags: haskell, data-structures, functional-programming, lisp, ml

In chapter 6.3.1 of the thesis [Purely Functional Data Structures](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf), says:

> Then, whenever we create a new tree from a new element and a segment
>   of trees of ranks 0... r-1, we simply compare the new element with the
>   ﬁrst root in the segment (i.e.,the root of the rank 0 tree). The
>   smaller element becomes the new root and the larger element becomes
>   the rank 0 child of the root.

1. T0' is the new tree has rank 0
2. T0..T(r-1) are the original trees rank 0 to r-1
3. The smaller element becomes the new root and the larger element becomes rank 0 child of the root

The question is that step 3 result in two rank 1 trees, which is conflict with the binomial heaps.

Am I misunderstanding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We are creating a tree of rank r. The structure of a tree of rank r is a root node with r children of ranks 0..r-1.

What the part you quoted means is this.

1. When we get a new element x we compare it to the element in T0
2. We create a new tree T0' of rank 0 containing the greater of the two compared elements
3. We create a new node T containing the lesser of the two compared elements and with T0',T1,T2...T(r-1) as children

Now T is a binomial tree of rank r and it is in heap order.

Comment: The heap contains r trees before and 1 tree after?

Comment: @wenlong: yes, r trees in the heap have been replaces with 1 tree. There might be other trees with ranks greater than r, though. They arent affected by this operation.